# What's wrong with my car battery?

Tags: battery, car, battery-charger

If I leave my car without starting for 4-5 days - the car won't start up. I have to jumpstart it (using a portable battery)

Using multimeter with the car off, it reads about 12.4V

Does the battery need to be replaced or can I trickle charge it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying the voltage is 12.4v when you try to start, or when you are done running the car?

Comment: When the car engine is off - but battery still hooked up to the car terminals.

Comment: Be weary about what your battery tester says: I checked my battery with a topdon the other day because all of a sudden my car wouldn't start right before work, the battery tester said it was bad, not that it needed charged, so I went and bought a battery and all was good up until I got curious. When I shook the old battery the voltage spiked 8 volts, then I took it inside the garage and charged it for a few hours, it would only go to 80% so I tried again later, now it doesnt drop to 80% in a week. If it gets too cold some people plug their vehicles in to avoid the hassle.

Comment: That's not what I meant, the question is *when* you measured the voltage. Did you measure after the car has sat for 4-5 days, or just after you have run the car?

Comment: Just after I jumpstarted it with a portable battery and ran for about 10 minutes. Using a multimeter, it's more like 12V, during cranking goes down to 8V and then 14V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your battery is bad. How old is the battery? If close to or more than five years old, it probably needs to be changed. Five years is the normal life span of a decent battery.

You say the battery reads at 12.4vdc when at rest. This is a good reading, however it is only part of the story. You need to have it load tested, where you test the voltage when under load. As @GdG is most likely getting to in comments, you can check the voltage drop when you crank the car. If it drops significantly, it could be in need of a new one. A battery shop or part store can do a more comprehensive test for you, which will give you the amount of reserve the battery has. This will go down as the battery gets older. It can show a good voltage, but not have any Amp hour reserves for actually being able to start the car.

Also, there may be a drain on the battery in the car, even when it's off. When the ignition switched off, pull the negative cable and put the leads of the multimeter between it and the negative battery post. You'll want the multimeter set to read amps to do this. When reading, there should be some draw, but it will most like be 80-100 mA. If a lot more than this, something in the car is draining the battery.

The battery may have been dying for some time now, but with it cold out, now it's rearing it's ugly head. Batteries and cold weather don't go together too well, so that may very well be what's going on.

Comment: I'll attach the multimeter and do an engine start and see what it reads and get back to you.

Comment: How about a battery charger - lead acid 12v on amazon around $100? Will that refurbish the battery?

Comment: @dashman - If you put a battery maintainer onto a bad battery overnight while the vehicle is sitting, it can make the battery last longer because it won't bleed off power. This will not refurbish a battery, though, only prolong your agony. Best to figure out exactly what the problem is and rememdy the situation from there.

Comment: Back from testing with multimeter. Cold the battery reads 12.0V. Then when I crank the engine goes down to about 8V and then 14V. What's the likely prognosis?

Comment: @dashman - Take it to a battery shop or retail store and have it load tested. It really shouldn't drop that kind of voltage while cranking.